# Await async clarification

Tags: .net, async-await, c#-5.0

I am trying to learn/understand more about async/await in C# and I would put myself in rookie category so all your comments/suggestions are welcome. I wrote small test to have better understanding and clarification about await/async. My program freezes after "GetStringLength" call I tried reading several things but looks like I am stuck and I thought of taking expert opinion on what I might be doing wrong. Can you please guide me or point me in right direction here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncPatterns
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            Task<string> url = p.FindLargtestWebPage(new Uri[]{new Uri("http://www.google.com"), 
                                                            new Uri("http://www.facebook.com"), 
                                                            new Uri("http://www.bing.com") });
            Console.WriteLine(url.Result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public async Task<string> FindLargtestWebPage(Uri[] uris)
        {
            string highCountUrl = string.Empty;
            int maxCount = 0;

            foreach (Uri uri in uris)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Processing {0}", uri.ToString()));
                var pageContent = await GetWebPageString(uri);
                var count = await GetStringLength(pageContent);
                if (count > maxCount)
                {
                    highCountUrl = uri.ToString();
                }
            }
            return highCountUrl;            
        }

        public async Task<int> GetStringLength(string pageData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting length");
            return await new Task<int>(() =>
            {
                return pageData.Length;
            });
        }

        public async Task<string> GetWebPageString(Uri uri)
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading string");
            return await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a good video explaining how it works and what it does http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_GTdR0gBVE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit for freezing is this:

```
return await new Task<int>(() =>
{
    return pageData.Length;
});
```

This `Task` constructor doesn't start the task, so you're creating a `Task` that isn't running. When you `await` on it in `GetStringLength` you're going to be waiting forever for the result.

You can either start the task manually:

```
var result = new Task<int>(() =>
{
    return pageData.Length;
});

result.Start();

return result;
```

or use the `Task.Run` static method, which will create and start the task:

```
return Task.Run(() =>
{
    return pageData.Length;
});
```

Comment: or just have a synchronized version of GetStringLength like Stephen says. I don't see a reason to use async here unless OP has other logic in real code.

Comment: Thanks !! Appreciate it. Thanks for pointing out reason for why is it freezing and for same reason I am accepting this as answer !!

Comment: @KaiWang: OP specifically says they're experimenting with `async`/`await`, so I read the question as "how could I get this to work", not a question about how the code *should* be written. As you say, this shouldn't really be an `async` method in "real" code :)

Comment: @Porges, sorry, my bad.

Comment: @KaiWang, no bad, it's something that I probably should have clarified

Answer (score 4):

Do not use the `Task` constructor in `async` code, and only use `async` when you have asynchronous work to do. `GetStringLength` has no asynchronous work to do, so it should be:

```
public int GetStringLength(string pageData)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Getting length");
  return pageData.Length;
}
```

For more information, see my [`async`/`await` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: Thanks !! Appreciate that.